# sql query re: display in user login page

Tags: sql

There is a database of all users in a network, I need to write a query where in when the user logs in. All the user id's should be displayed in page except his.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more clear about what you're trying to do, what you have already tried and what context you're in (ASP.NET, PHP, etc) We can't really help you this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all users except the current one, you could use something like

```
SELECT id FROM members WHERE id <> currentID
```

Comment: "Not sure what plzz hlp thnx means", weird, that was the only part of the question I understood...

Comment: I just saw the "plzz hlp thnx" and almost flagged this "not an answer"!

Answer (score 0):

Lex's comment is valid. I will tell you what you'd need if this were an asp.net question: the general principle may help you.

1. 'When the user logs in' means you have some system where people log in, and, presumably, you can detect this event - like in an asp.net login page.
2. You then want to show something: this means you probably have the flexibility (in your design / coding) to show it. Say: an asp.net page.
3. In that case, you can, when the page loads (page_load), get the user id for that user (using membership routines if asp.net) and then use that userid as a parameter
4. That parameter would be 'currentID' in Gaby's example, for instance.

I could give more detail, but given the general nature of your question, that might be wasted effort at this time.